# How do I use LocalStorage to save picked background colors for buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

The problem is that I don't know how to to use LocalStorage to save picked background-colors for the buttons. I have never used LocalStorage before but my idea for the code is to somehow use myFunction(color), which make use of the color value from the onclick function. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover
({
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    trigger: 'focus',
    content: function()
    {
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
  });
  let targetBtn;
  document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn').forEach((item) =>
  {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) =>
    {
      targetBtn = e.target;
    })
  })
  function myFunction(color)
  {
    if (targetBtn)
    {
      targetBtn.style.background = color;
      /* Here I somehow want to use localStorage
         to save the picked colors for the buttons 
         localStorage.setItem('targetBtn', color); */
    }
  }
```

```css
    .popover-content
    {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items:center;
      background: #efefef;
      width: 230px;
      height: 80px;
    }
    .close
    {
      color: #aaaaaa;
      float: right;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:210px;
    }
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus
    {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .myBtn
    {
      background-color: #DCDCDC;
      border: 0.5px solid #808080;
      color: white;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 6%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .demo1
    {
      background-color: red;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .demo2
    {
      background-color: green;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .demo3
    {
      background-color: blue;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .hide
    {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="myBtn myBtnCorners1" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">1</button>
      <button class="myBtn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">2</button>
  <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <button class="demo1" onclick="myFunction('red')">Red</button>
    <button class="demo2" onclick="myFunction('green')">Green</button>
    <button class="demo3" onclick="myFunction('blue')">Blue</button>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A lot of your code does not seem to make sense. What have you tried so far? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to test in the Snippet but the code should be good.

You will need a Getter and a Setter. Once you have them, you can get, set or load all the preferences.

```js
var getColorPref = (i) => {
  return localStorage.getItem("color-" + i) || "";
}

var saveColorPref = (i, c) => {
  localStorage.setItem("color-" + i, c);
  return c;
}

var loadColorPrefs = () => {
  $(".myBtn").each(() => {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $(this).css("background", getColorPref(i));
  });
}

loadColorPrefs();

var targetBtn;

function setColor(c) {
  var i = $(targetBtn).index();
  console.log(i, c);
  $(targetBtn).css("background", saveColorPref(i, c));
}

$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  sanitize: false,
  trigger: 'focus',
  content: function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  }
});

$('.myBtn').each((i, item) => {
  $(item).click((e) => {
    targetBtn = e.target;
  });
});
```

```css
.popover-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: #efefef;
  width: 230px;
  height: 80px;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 210px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.myBtn {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border: 0.5px solid #808080;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 6%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.demo1 {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.demo2 {
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.demo3 {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="myBtn myBtnCorners1" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">1</button>
  <button class="myBtn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">2</button>
  <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <button class="demo1" onClick="setColor('red')">Red</button>
    <button class="demo2" onClick="setColor('green')">Green</button>
    <button class="demo3" onClick="setColor('blue')">Blue</button>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You save something to local storage by:

`localStorage.setItem('whatever you wanna save goes here');`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer/solution,

Comment: It should be something `localstorage.setItem('myColor', color);` The value to be stored should be passed to the function as well, along with the name of the item you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

OP asked explicitly about saving to localStorage, so Leira Sánchez's answer is correct. I believe OP is asking about getting data from localStorage as well, so I will elaborate.

I would suggest adding ids to your HTML buttons to save the colors explicitly:

```
<button id="myBtn1" class="myBtn myBtnCorners1" ...>1</button>
<button id="myBtn2" class="myBtn"...>2</button>
```

`myFunction()` should now be able to obtain `targetBtn.id`, and you would save to localStorage something like this:

```
function myFunction(color) {
  if (targetBtn) {
    targetBtn.style.background = color;
    localStorage.setItem(targetBtn.id, color);
  }
}
```

In your document.getQuerySelector you could then get the items from localStorage and apply the style

```
  document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn').forEach((item) => {
    const id = $(item).attr("id")
    $(item).css("background-color", localStorage.getItem(id));

    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      targetBtn = e.target;
    })
  })
```